# Testcontainers - postgres + Quarkus test resulting in NoClassDefFound on LogMessageWaitStrategy

Tags: junit, quarkus, testcontainers

I have a project runinng on Quarkus 2.3.0.CR1 with the following primary dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.0.Beta1</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.20</org.projectlombok.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.3.0.CR1</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <testcontainers.version>1.12.2</testcontainers.version>
  </properties>

<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have this container setup for testcontainers:

```
class MySingletonContainerextends PostgreSQLContainer<MySingletonContainer>{

  private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:latest";
  static MySingletonContainercontainer;

  public static MySingletonContainer getInstance() {
    if (container == null) {
      container = new MySingletonContainer();
    }
    return container;
  }


  public MySingletonContainer() {
    super(IMAGE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {
    super.start();
    System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
    System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
    System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    // No-op. Shutdown only on JVM shutdown
  }

}
```

This test resource

```
public class PostgresResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

  static MySingletonContainerdb = MySingletonContainer.getInstance();

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> start() {
    db.start();
    return Collections.singletonMap("quarkus.datasource.url", db.container.getJdbcUrl());
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    db.stop();
  }
}
```

and this test application.yaml:

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
      db-kind: postgresql
      jdbc: false
      username: ${DB_USERNAME}
      password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      reactive:
        url: ${DB_URL}
        max-size: 20
```

and finally my test is annotated as such:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(PostgresResource.class)
public class MyTest {
}
```

I am running windows 10 pro with docker installed using Docker Desktop on WSL2

When i run the test I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException however:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:574)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:226)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:551)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:589)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testcontainers/containers/wait/LogMessageWaitStrategy
    at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.<init>(PostgreSQLContainer.java:33)
    at my.package.MySingletonContainer.<init>(MySingletonContainer .java:19)
    at my.package.MySingletonContainer.getInstance(MySingletonContainer .java:12)
    at my.package.PostgresResource.<clinit>(PostgresResource.java:9)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466)
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager.loadTestResourceClassFromTCCL(TestResourceManager.java:365)
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager.getUniqueTestResourceClassEntries(TestResourceManager.java:284)
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager.<init>(TestResourceManager.java:64)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testcontainers.containers.wait.LogMessageWaitStrategy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:455)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
    ... 56 more
```

I can't see any dependnecies that might be clashing offhand as only the testcontainers one was added. What can be going wrong?

Comment: Quarkus 2.0+ uses internally testcontainers to setup some containers for you so you don't need to to that, if you still want to use them, don't override quarkus testcontainers version. I see in your pom that you are not using a specific version of testcontainers in the declaration of the dependency, by you have the property defined, are you using this property elsewhere?

Comment: If you want to disable quarkus devTools, which is the feature that uses testcontainers to setup a development envinroment for you, check this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services

Comment: This indeed seems to have been the case. I had the version injected in devDependencies in a parent pom and it was conflicting.   (If you post this as an answer i'll be glad to mark as the correct answer :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus 2.0+ includes a new system call devServices which uses internally testcontainers to setup a development an testing environment for you, so you don't need to deal with this kind of things, [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services) is a guide about the topic.

I see that you are not specifying a version in your testcontainers dependency, but you the property defined, if you are using this property to specify some testcontainers dependency this might be the issue and causing the conflict.